# How JS 'arguments' object gets converted to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

Looking for more details on what exactly is happening when following is executed:

```
    function useArray(){
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments)
        console.log(args)
    }
```

How come `slice` being a function with 3 parameters (source array, start and end positions to copy) threats `arguments` correctly? Method `call` needs correct value of first argument as `this` but it seems `arguments` gets turned into Array object?

And why this doesn't work:

```
var args = [].slice(arguments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using `[].slice` to get at the `Array::slice` method. `arguments` doesn't have a `slice()` of its own, but it *is* array-like.

Although it's a member of `Array`, `slice()` will work well enough on array-like objects -- things that have `.length` and can be indexed with `[0..n]`.

`slice()` with no parameters returns a copy of the entire array.  Its arguments are both optional.

So it's as if `arguments` *had* a `slice()` method, and we called `arguments.slice()` to get a copy of it (as an array).

`[].slice(arguments)` is just calling `Array::slice()` on an empty array, with `arguments` as the `begin` parameter, which makes no sense since `begin` (if present) should be a number.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. It is clear now why `[].slice(arguments)` returns empty array. One more thing to double-check though. Am I right, saying that `[].slice.call(arguments)` passes object `arguments` as the receiver of the call, that `call()` method of function object is supposed to have as the first argument?

Comment: If I read that correctly, yes. It's as if `slice` was temporarily a member of `arguments` -- `arguments` would be `this` within that `slice` call.